# RAM Not Getting Detected

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, troubleshooting

I have Lenovo IdeaPad 320E. It has 1x4GB on-board RAM and another 1x4GB dedicated RAM stick. The dedicated stick or slot seems to be not working. In BIOS/Task Manager, it is showing 4GB of RAM, also in Task Manager it is showing 1 of 2 slots is in use.

For troubleshooting, I tried removing the stick, cleaning the connector pins and slot and putting it back again. When I did this for first time, it showed me correct 8GB. Then I tried restarting the laptop and since then again its showing 4GB.

Is the stick not working or the slot? How can I check what is the cause?

Task Manager Snap:
[image: Task Manager Snap]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem.  Have you considered replacing the module?

Comment: Yes. Tried replacing it. Same issue. By the way, the motherboard supports 2133MHz. I tried replacing it with 2400MHz.Will the motherboard support 2400MHz?

Comment: No; It does not support 2400 MHz modules

Comment: If the issue was in RAM slot, then would the Task Manager have shown `1 of 2 slots`??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another issue can be when not putting RAM correctly in. Does not happen to often but not fully plugged in RAM will not work. It just will be ignored by System.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to check if the slot is working would be to simply put the original ram chip in the second slot and try booting. If you encounter no errors and the pc shows 4g of ram you know the slot isn’t the problem. Before doing this though have you compared the two RAM chips to ensure they are identical?